# Azure autoscale preview how it works

Tags: azure

I saw a "auto scale preview" on my management portal. When I clicked on it it says:
"You need to configure the autoscale service."

I tried to look up on MSDN and could not find anything helpful but detail EntLib.

Could someone please clarify how this feature works
?

Comment: Check out this blog post from Scott Guthrie: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/27/windows-azure-general-availability-release-of-web-sites-mobile-services-new-autoscale-alerts-support-no-credit-card-needed-for-msdn-subscribers.aspx. Also this blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2013/06/28/the-new-auto-scaling-service-in-windows-azure.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Autoscale functionality in the Azure portal is a UI-only feature at this time. If you want to configure Autoscale via API, I'd recommend WASABi.

ScottGu has a blog post here about this: [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/27/windows-azure-general-availability-release-of-web-sites-mobile-services-new-autoscale-alerts-support-no-credit-card-needed-for-msdn-subscribers.aspx)

When you click on the link to "Configure Autoscale" from the Dashboard in the management portal, it takes you to the **Scale** tab for the service you want to scale (be that your Cloud Service, Web site etc...).

On the Scale tab, there is a list of components inside your service. For Cloud Services, for example, it's a list of all of the roles. You can turn on autoscale for any one of these items by selecting **CPU** or **Queue** from the Autoscale switch (see [this screenshot](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/scottgu/image_thumb_1F4C53A5.png))

Once you've chosen the metric, you define the range that autoscale operates over. At the above link, Azure would autoscale between 1 and 5 instances. When CPU drops below the target range, an instance will be removed, and when it exceeds the target range an instance would be added.

Comment: It's worth noting that the average CPU needs to be above or below the max/min value for **one hour** before it performs a scaling operation.

Comment: @greg84 Is there any official documentation that supports your "one hour" claim? I'm trying to research more into when exactly Azure adds (or drops) an instance.

Comment: If you hover over the question mark in the portal next to the "scale up by x instances at a  time" controls, the tooltip says: "Windows Azure checks to determine whether your average CPU usage is high over an hour, and adds this number of instances as needed. Increase this number to add virtual machines more quickly."